# WinForms Form_Load not called

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have a form that inherits from a base form. There is code both in the `baseform_load` and `childform_load` events.

The BaseForm looks like this:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

And a child form might look like this:

```
public partial class ChildForm : BaseForm
{
    public ChildForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChildForm _Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

The `baseform`'s load event is not explicitly loaded. The event handlers are also available because they're being created through the form designer.

I open my forms with the following method:

```
public static DialogResult ShowForm<T>(this Form form, bool canShowForm) where T : Form, new()
{
    return new T().ShowDialog(form);
}
```

Everything was working fine, but all of a sudden, neither the code in the `baseform` nor `childform` load events is being called.

Note: I'm calling `InitializeComponent` in my `childform` constructor and it doesn't raise any exception.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to include all the relevant information.. does the `childform` call the `baseform`s load event? There isn't really enough information here to determine the cause

Comment: you need to declare & define  form_load event manually ...

Comment: I prefer to use FormShown event to initialize the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the event handlers aren't subscribed (due to overriding the base class' `InitializeComponents`). Add this to the constructor:

```
this.Load += BaseForm_Load;
```

Pro tip: You might want to look onto overriding [`Form.OnLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you do so, it calls the `OnLoad` on the derived classes automatically, so it doesn't need event subscription.

Something like:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e); // let the base class do it's OnLoad

    //Do your own stuff...
}
```

Comment: I was using this method but it wasn't working. When I debug through code neither OnLoad method is called (BaseForm nor ChildForm)

Comment: I tried your code and it does work... Are your sure the derived partial classes aren't breaking you up? I always prefer to have a non-designer base form.

Comment: My code was working fine till now!! What do you mean by breaking you up? Edit: It's not even working when I move the code to OnShown methods.

Comment: Can you make a stripped sample? Include the designer code files too please.

Comment: A new project with 2 simple forms and using the above extension method works fine. Could it be obsolete code in InitializeComponent from when I changed code from Form_Load() to Onload()?

Comment: You are calling the `InitializeComponents` method in both the base as derived class, that might be the root cause.

Comment: Another child form is working fine. This particular form is not.

Comment: Hmmm.. That doesn't make sense... Is there more code you want to share about this particular form? Try to create a new form and build it up with the code you have step by step.

Comment: If I comment the InitializeComponent in the childform, the OnLoad events are raised correctly. However, no controls will be displayed in the childform. This childform is more complex with multiple user controls. If I step through code in InitializeComponent, the method doesn't raise an exception...

Comment: Problem solved! The controls are bound to a bindingsource. Some properties of the source have been renamed but the bindingsource was still referencing the old properties. Updating the bindingsource solved the problem.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: Okay! Glad you found it.